# How can I simplify this boolean literals wrapped into if-then-else into a single invocation to conform to sonarqube. Thanks

Tags: java, sonarqube

```
@Override
protected boolean willFlightBeChanged(AwbFlt awbFlt) {
    if (CargoMaxUtil.isHostCarrier(awbFlt.carrier()) && (!Str.equals(awbFlt.alloc, AwbFlt.ALLOC_UU)))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general:

```
if (condition)
  return true;
return false;
```

is exactly the same as:

```
return condition;
```

So:

```
return CargoMaxUtil.isHostCarrier(awbFlt.carrier()) && (!Str.equals(awbFlt.alloc, AwbFlt.ALLOC_UU));
```